# Export user favorite to excel code is not working

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to export the user favorited to Excel in frontend but it's not working  I tried with integrating PHP and javascript but it's not working. I am using WordPress. I am giving this code in an HTML widget in elementor.

how to integrate this php and javascript .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Export to Excel</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.17.0/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.17.0/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.0/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="exportToExcel()">Export to Excel</button>

    <script>
        function exportToExcel() {
             <?php
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            $favorites = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'my_favorites', true);
            $export_data = array();

            if (!empty($favorites)) {
                foreach ($favorites as $favorite) {
                    $post = get_post($favorite);
                    if ($post) {
                        $funder_name = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-grant-funder-name', true);
                        $grant_amount = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-grant-amount', true);
                        $grantFinalClosingDate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-grant-final-closing-date', true);
                        $grantDuration = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-grant-duration', true);
                        $grantUrl = get_permalink($post->ID); // Get the grant URL as the permalink

                        // Truncate the URL to a specific length
                        $max_url_length = 25; // Adjust the desired maximum length
                        if (strlen($grantUrl) > $max_url_length) {
                            $grantUrl = substr($grantUrl, 0, $max_url_length) . '...';
                        }

                        $export_data[] = array(
                            'Grant title' => $post->post_title,
                            'Funder name' => $funder_name,
                            'Grant amount' => $grant_amount,
                            'Deadline' => date_i18n(get_option('date_format'), $grantFinalClosingDate),
                            'Duration' => $grantDuration,
                            'Grant URL' => $grantUrl
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>

            var data = <?php echo json_encode($export_data); ?>;

            var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
            var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
            XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');

            var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'binary' });

            function s2ab(s) {
                var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
                var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
                for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
                return buf;
            }

            saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }), 'export.xlsx');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

please guide me on what is wrong here.